# How to Moderate Facebook Comments in mediawki

Tags: facebook, mediawiki, facebook-comments

I am using a [widget Facebook Comment](http://www.mediawikiwidgets.org/Facebook_Comments) in my MediaWiki site.

The widget is showing facebook comment box properly and it is functioning good except that I can't moderate the comments.
The installation says:

> You have to set fb:app_id open graph property too indicate to Facebook that you're the administrator of the site and can moderate comments and add section.

But I didn't understad this line. If someone know the way please post with some example.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not added an App Id, go to `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/`
Click on "Apps" pull down menu, Click "Create a New App" and create a new application with your website name, it will generate an Application Id, use that in your website meta tag as below:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="<your App id>" />
```

And ofcourse other meta tags as well,

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="<your admin id>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<website logo image url>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<Site name>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<webpage completel url>" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<title>" />
```

After that you should be set!

Comment: Thank you I shall try.
Where the meta tags should be placed ? Is it in the vector.php as I use vector skin in my mediawiki site.

Comment: It should be in the head tag of html. between <head> and </head>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After hours, I found a solution... In facts there is very little errors in the code on the widget page...

In `LocalSettings.php`, copy-paste this (xxxxx = your FB IPapp number) and it will work:

```
$wgExtensionFunctions[] = 'mww_fb_app_id';
function mww_fb_app_id() {
        global $wgOut;
        $wgOut->addHeadItem ( "fb:app_id" , '<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxx"/>');

}
```